# How to Calculate the Average after a certain date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, date, average

Im trying to get the average of days taken to send to college but i only want it to take in to consideration dates received after 17/05/2021.

can anyone help

[image: Picture Help]

Comment: DATE RECEIVED CELL N

Comment: DAYS TAKEN TO SEND TO THE COLLEGE CELL S

Comment: Use AVERAGEIF  to do this

Comment: @PeterH i have tried but i carnt get the formula to work

Comment: your question doesn't make it easy to provide you with answer, re write it show exactly what you ahve and what you want it to look like using sample data etc.

Comment: @PeterH - i have attached a picture to the post, i want to work out the average days taken to send to college but for date received after 17/05/2021

Comment: SUMIF and COUNTIF functions?

Answer (score 0):

With dates in **A1** through **A10** and take in **B1** to **B10**, Pick a cell and enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10>=DATE(2021,5,17)),B1:B10)/SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A10>=DATE(2021,5,17)))
```

[image]

With Excel365 you could use the `FILTER()` function.

Comment: i have added a picture for example

Comment: @StephanieYoung  I cannot see your picture.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7mLC.png